# A RenderFlex overflowed by 80 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

The page got an error "A RenderFlex overflowed by 80 pixels on the bottom". How can you fix it?

```js
class FavNews extends StatelessWidget {
  final FavoritesController controller = Get.find();

  FavNews({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() {
      return SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: controller.news.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return FavNewsItem(
                article: controller.news.keys.toList()[index],
                index: index,
              );
            }),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of output?

Comment: Attached a screenshot

Comment: The problem is the `height` of `SizedBox()`. Remove `SizedBox` widget once.

Comment: share Obx widget code

Answer (score 0):

Put it Sizedbox inside a SingleChildScrollView widget.

```
 return SingleChildScrollView(
     child: SizedBox(
       height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
       child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: controller.news.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return FavNewsItem(
            article: controller.news.keys.toList()[index],
            index: index,
          );
        }),)
```

Just try it. It may work

Comment: Your solution doesn't work, but thanks)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the height of your SizedBox.
`MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` return the height of your entire screen including statusbar, appbar and system gestires at the bottom.

With `ListView.builder` you can use `shrinkWrap: true` that will use only the space that it acutally need to use.

Example:

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
  child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: controller.news.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return FavNewsItem(
                article: controller.news.keys.toList()[index],
                index: index,
              );
            }),
         ),
   );
```

Comment: Your solution worked, but when I add content to the page, I get this error again

Comment: What do you mean by content? other widgets under the list view builder?
That means that the list view items occupy the entire page and so the widget is being placed below it.
If you need to add other widgets below the listview you need to set a fixed or proportional height to your listview to reserve space below it.

Comment: Just Wrap ListView.builder with SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: @Maqsood you're right thanks, forgot about that. I added in the example code.

Answer (score 0):

do not hardcoat the height while using the scrollbar  remove the height attribute and it'll work just fine

````
  final FavoritesController controller = Get.find();

  FavNews({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() {
      return SizedBox(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: controller.news.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return FavNewsItem(
                article: controller.news.keys.toList()[index],
                index: index,
              );
            }),
      );
    });
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

you do not need `sizedBox`

```
return Obx(() {
return ListView.builder(
        srinkWrap: true;
        itemCount: controller.news.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return FavNewsItem(
            article: controller.news.keys.toList()[index],
            index: index,
          );
        }),);
}
```